# Fatal error: L3900U: Unrecognized option '--no_import_unresolved' in Verifone vx 820

Tags: makefile, point-of-sale, verifone

I want to use SDK VX GUI for developing app on VeriFone vx 820.
I use make file below and in compile step its compile OK but in linking step its faced error `Fatal error: L3900U: Unrecognized option '--no_import_unresolved'`

How can i fix it?

My make file is:
    #
    # nmake makefile to build a sample VxGUI client application

```
#VRXSDK=C:\eVoAps\VRXSDK\3.7.4
#VXEOS =C:\eVoAps\EOSSDK\1.7.1.0

VRXSDK=C:\eVoAps\SDK\1.2.0\VRXSDK
VXEOS=C:\eVoAps\SDK\1.2.0\EOSSDK



# to use VxGUI EnableHeader() method, 1.2.0 SDK and VxGUI task are required
# VXGUISDK=c:\evoAps\VxGUISDK\1.2.0.6
VXGUISDK=C:\eVoAps\SDK\1.2.0\GUISDK

VRXIncludes = $(VRXSDK)\include
EOSIncludes = $(VXEOS)\include

SrcDir = .
ObjDir = .
OutDir = .

VXGUISDKInclude = $(VXGUISDK)\include

Includes = -I$(VRXIncludes) -I$(VXGUISDKInclude) -I$(EOSIncludes)
# Compiler options - ignoring warnings on "inherits implicit virtual" and
# "overloaded virtual function only partially overridden..." and
# "nested comments not allowed" and
# Note that warnings on missing return statements will still be generated due to the VxGUI headers
COptions = -p -g -vsoapp -armcc,"--diag_suppress 1300\,611\,9" -D LOGSYS_FLAG -D LOGSYS_NEW_API_STYLE 
LinkOptions = -vsoapp -g -p 

Libs = \
    $(VXGUISDK)\lib\libvxguisdk.so  \
    $(VXEOS)\lib\ceif.o \
    $(VXEOS)\lib\elog.o


AppObjects = \
        $(ObjDir)\hello.o 


pseudoOut : $(OutDir)\hello.vsa.p7s

$(OutDir)\hello.vsa.p7s : $(OutDir)\hello.vsa 
    "$(VSFSTOOL)\filesignature" .\hello.fst -nogui

$(OutDir)\hello.vsa : $(AppObjects)
    $(VRXSDK)\bin\vrxcc $(LinkOptions) $(AppObjects) $(Libs) -o $@
    $(VRXSDK)\bin\vrxhdr -s 75000 -h 50000 -lELOG.LIB=N:/ELOG.LIB -lceif.lib=N:/CEIF.LIB $(OutDir)\hello.vsa

######  Compile #######
$(ObjDir)\hello.o : $(SrcDir)\hello.cpp 
    $(VRXSDK)\bin\vrxcc -c $(Includes)  $(COptions) $(SrcDir)\hello.cpp -o $@
```

Comment: Have you know reason of it?

Answer (score 0):

What is your armcc version?

I'dont have this version, but, from: Verix eVo GUI SDK Release Notes / Version 1.4.7.1

### 2. Software Requirements:

```
VFSDK 1.1.0 or later which includes:
VRXSDK 3.5.0 or later
EOSSDK 1.8.0 or later
**RVDS 4.0 (bin: 902; inc & lib: 902)**
```

checkout your version at prompt (cmd) with:

### armcc --vsn

**ARMC C/C++ Compiler, RVCT4.0 [Build 902] for Verifone**